# AJAX request doesn't go through

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to call a function on the server through AJAX. The problem is that the request goes through for one url but not for the other.

here's my code :

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/user/Default.aspx/Decline") %>',
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (msg) {
                //var resultAsJson = msg.d // your return result is JS array
                //// Now you can loop over the array to get each object
                //var class_no = parseInt(resultAsJson[2]);
                //document.getElementsByClassName("notif_body")[class_no].innerHTML = resultAsJson[0] + " is now following you";
                alert(msg.d);


            }

        });
```

When I change the url to :

```
url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/myaccount/notifications/Default.aspx/Decline") %>',
```

The function gets called on this file but not the other.

The function I'm trying to call is as follows:

```
        [WebMethod]
    public static string Decline()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
```

Comment: are you sure the namespace is correct? Post that for us too (top of your code behind file)

Comment: The function I'm trying to call in the file didn't have any name space. I've added that so let me see if it works now

Comment: if it's c# there should be `namespace` just below your using statements before you declare the class

Comment: @godmode It won't let me use user control functions when I include the name space. I get "Error58 The name 'connect_v21' does not exist in the current context" connect_v21 is the user control.

Comment: how big is the file, can you post the whole page?

Comment: Sorry I'm asking really basic questions. I'm learning this stuff so most things are not known to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93807/discussion-between-godmode-and-ahmed-mujtaba).

Comment: @godmode it's about 700 lines. here :http://pastebin.com/sfvvLfKQ

Comment: @godmode I have created a new web service file. I'm testing my functions by sending requests through Fiddler but I'm getting (500 Internal Server) error. Will you be able to help me with that

Comment: The post requests to other methods inside .aspx files go through fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahmed, sounds like it was the namespace.

Set this as the answer so the question can be closed